# Converting elapsed milliseconds into proper java date format?

Tags: java, datetime, elapsedtime, elapsed

I stuck up in the middle of my development, I have requirement in such a way that i need to find the delay between two dates ie.. `currentdate-date from database`

and i need to display the delay in the format of `dd:hh:mm` . After referring lot of references i found how to convert to individual milliseconds hours and minutes , but what am expecting: if the result is some X milliseconds , i need to show it in proper day minute and seconds format

**example : 2days:03minutes:46seconds**

Here is the code am using :

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTime(date);
calendar2.setTime(date1);
long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
long diff = milliseconds1 - milliseconds2;
System.out.println("diff ::"+diff);
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

can anyone please suggest me what to do further? 
Please guide me ..

Comment: In that code, you are assuming that every day has 24 hours, and every hour 60 minutes, and every minute has 60 seconds. This will not work in countries with daylight savings time, nor on planets with leap seconds. You should use a calendar framework like Joda Time instead and let that do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @wallenborn , yeah now doing background work on joda time , can you please help me how to use it

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first compute `diffDays`

```
diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Then compute the remaining milliseconds:

```
diff -= diffDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Use the new diff to compute the diffHours and so on...

A suggestions: use constant values like this:

```
private static final int SECOND = 1000;
private static final int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
// and so on
```

Comment: Dan can u please explain me a bit detail

Comment: This assumes every day has 24 hours, which will fail twice every year if you live in an area with daylight savings time.

Comment: What other edge cases can you find? Maybe you can down-vote for each one.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). The Java API doesn't contain anything dealing with "the difference between two date/time values". In Joda Time you can choose between `Period` (which is really for a calendar-centric difference) and a `Duration` (which is really just an elapsed time difference).

Ideally, use Joda Time for *all* your date/time concerns - it's a much, more better API.

In this case, I suspect you've *logically* got a `Duration`, but you'll want to convert it into a `Period` in order to use a [`PeriodFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) for string conversions.

Comment: can you please provide some examples for joda time

Comment: @Esh: Well, what did you try?

Comment: so far i tried getting the hours and minutes separately ,now am stuck in chronology concept , i want to set the chronology to '000' , buts its taking the default one as ISOChronology[Asia/Kolkata], dont know how to override it

Comment: @Esh: What do you mean by "000"? It sounds like you may want `ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC`.

Comment: ,. i ll post my work in       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577222/how-to-use-joda-date-and-time-api. please guide me

Answer (score 1):

**-** I would recommend using the `Joda` Library when you deal with any date-time issues.

**Joda Time has a concept of time Interval:**

`Interval interval = new Interval(oldTime, new Instant());`

By the way, Joda has two concepts: Interval for representing an interval of time between two time instants (represent time between 8am and 10am), and a Duration that represents a length of time without the actual time boundaries (e.g. represent two hours!)

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

With JodaTime this is really easy. See the following code:

```
public void testJoda() {
    DateTime then = new DateTime("2012-03-23T02:30:00.000");
    DateTime now = new DateTime("2012-03-24T02:29:00.000");

    DurationFieldType[] ddhhmm = { DurationFieldType.days(),
            DurationFieldType.hours(), DurationFieldType.minutes() };
    Period p = new Period(then, now, PeriodType.forFields(ddhhmm));
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    p = new Period(then, now, PeriodType.days());
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    p = new Period(then, now, PeriodType.hours());
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    DurationFieldType[] hhmm  = { DurationFieldType.hours(), DurationFieldType.minutes() };
    p = new Period(then, now, PeriodType.forFields(hhmm));
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

which tests for an interval of 23h59m. Its output is as expected:

```
PT23H59M
P0D
PT23H
PT23H59M
```

Take the same interval, one day later, just around the spring DST jump on March 25th:

```
DateTime then = new DateTime("2012-03-24T02:30:00.000");
DateTime now = new DateTime("2012-03-25T03:29:00.000");
```

and you correctly get:

```
P1DT-1M
P1D
PT23H
PT23H59M
```

It doesn't get much easier than that, really.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTime(date);
calendar2.setTime(date1);

int dayDiff = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
int hourDiff = calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) -calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);   
int dayDiff = calendar1.get(Calendar.SECOND) - calendar2.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(   // Represent a span of time, unattached to the timeline.
    earlier ,       // `Instant` class represents a moment in UTC with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds. Current moment captured in microseconds, depending on capability of host computer hardware and operating system.
    Instant.now()
)                   // Returns a `Duration` object. Call `to…Part` methods to get the days, hours, minutes, seconds as separate numbers.
```

## java.time

So much easier when using the modern *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

Get the current moment in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

The current moment is captured in [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) in Java 8 specifically. In Java 9 and later, you may see the current moment captured with a finer granularity due to a fresh implementation of `Clock`. In Oracle Java 9 JDK on macOS Sierra, I get the current moment in [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) (six digits of decimal fraction second).

```
Instant earlier = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant later = Instant.now() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time as a span-of-time unattached to the timeline. For a scale of hours-minutes-seconds (and days as 24-hour chunks of time unrelated to calendar), use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). For a scale of years-months-days, use `Period`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( earlier , later ) ;
```

Generate a String is [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`, where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds.

```
String output = d.toString() ;  // Standard ISO 8601 format.
```

I strongly recommend using the standard formats rather than the format seen in the Question. I have seen the time-of-day format cause so much confusion and ambiguity where it can be mistaken for, well, a time-of-day rather than a span-of-time. The ISO 8601 formats were wisely designed to avoid such ambiguities. But if you insist, in Java 9 and later you may ask for the parts of a `Duration` by calling the `to…Part` methods.

```
long days = d.toDaysPart() ;  // 24-hour chunks of time, unrelated to calendar dates.
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
```

Then assemble as you desire into a string.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).